# Git failing on 'Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl'

Tags: git, macos, curl, https, macports

When I run `git push`, I get this error message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxxx/yyyy.git/': Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

`curl --version` does show https in the supported protocols, and `which curl` returns `/usr/bin/curl`. But I had seen some other forum posts which suggested a manual install of curl with brew / macports, so I tried via MacPorts, with +ssl. Now `curl --version` shows:

```
$ curl -h
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/curl
  Reason: Incompatible library version: curl requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0
Abort trap: 6
```

and `which curl` returns `/opt/local/bin/curl`.

I decided this might be a good time to upgrade to OSX Sierra to see if a fresh install might clean things up, to no avail. This also included a complete clean + reinstall + rebuild of all my MacPorts, to no avail. I also tried a fresh reinstall of Git.

What's broken, and how do I fix this?

Comment: git uses an internal copy of curl I think, libcurl, which may or may not be using the same configuration. Can you please set the `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` environment variable to `1` and retry? Also, which version of git are you using?

Comment: The crash when running `(/opt/local/bin/)curl -h` is most likely due to a `DYLD_*` variable in the environment. Check using `(set | grep DYLD_)`, using `/usr/bin/env` or `/usr/bin/printenv` will not show them. This may, or may not also cause your problems with Git failing to use TLS.

Comment: @neverpanic: That was it. Apparently some months ago, I had added something to the DYLD_* paths to get some (messy) researcher's code working. After removing the export, it finally works. Thank you!